# How to install libprotobuf?

Tags: linux, protocol-buffers

By mistake i have deleted these libraries. I couldn't find a right way to reinstall it.

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-c.so.0
```

To fix it, i tried to follow these instructions, https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md
but ended up with different version. Now while compiling my code it throws this error. How can i get my previous version back?

```
error while loading shared libraries: libprotoc.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tried a simple reinstall with `apt-get`?

Comment: can you give me the full command?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but should be `apt-get install --reinstall libprotobuf-dev`.

Comment: @Siguza It didn't work out

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall libprotobuf8 libprotobuf-c0`

Comment: Build **Protobuf 2.5.0** version. After building this version it will create **libprotobuf.so.8**. To build Protobuf 2.5.0 you can follow the instructions from https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/v2.5.0/

Comment: Why is this question getting voted down and why is snehal's answer turned into a comment??? snehal's answer is EXACTLY the right answer assuming you need to install from source and at worse this question is simply on the wrong exchange (which I'm not sure whether it is or not), in which case just point the user at "Unix & Linux" or "Super User".

Comment: @CrazyCasta I agree. I just posted it in wrong forum, that doesn't mean question is wrong.

Answer (score 11):

Unknown OS: Installing the three packages providing libprotobuf.so.8, libprotobuf-c.so.0, libprotoc.so.8 →

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libprotobuf8 libprotobuf-c0 libprotoc8
```

HOWTO decide a package :

```
sudo apt install apt-file 
apt-file search libprotoc.so.8
```

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libprotoc&searchon=names

Comment: Great. This installed libprotobuf.so.8.  But i am still seeing this error while compiling my code.. any idea how to fix this?   /usr/bin/protoc-c: error while loading shared libraries: libprotoc.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [t/test.pb-c.c] Error 127

Comment: My answer was edited : `apt install --reinstall libprotobuf8 libprotobuf-c0 libprotoc8` and HOWTO decide a package.